# make select box values faded out/unclickable

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a normal HTML select dropdown box

```
<select id="day" name="day">
<option value="0">All</option>
<option value="1">Mon</option>
<option value="2">Tue</option>
<option value="3">Wed</option>
<option value="4">Thu</option>
<option value="5">Fri</option>
</select>
```

But on occassion I want to make some options not clickable, e.g. the Text faded out slightly if possible, and then nothing to happen if the text/value is selected.

Anyone know how?

I'm writing my page in PHP.

Comment: Oh. You want the options disabled, not the whole select box. I deleted my answer cause I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I had previosuly written a jQuery solution for this if that's acceptable.

I Don't have a pure JS fix unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE 6 requires javascript to disable an item. There is a bug that prevents it from disabling individual items.

See here for details on how to implement this so that it functions in IE6:
http://www.lattimore.id.au/2005/07/01/select-option-disabled-and-the-javascript-solution/

Comment: OK thanks guys. I'll have a look through this shortly hopefully. It looks like it will be the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Simply give the option tag an attribute 'disabled'.

```
<select>
<option value="1" disabled>1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

So in this example, 1 will be faded out and un-selectable but 2 will be selectable.

Comment: I'm using IE7 and it's not working. Anyone know an alternative or how to get around this?

Comment: This is not valid XTML, if that's what you're declaring your page to be. Use `disabled="disabled"` instead. Browsers will probably render it properly anyway (besides IE apparently and of course), but it may cause problems somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

There is a javascript solution here

http://www.lattimore.id.au/2005/07/01/select-option-disabled-and-the-javascript-solution/

There is no way to do this in IE without a JS hack sadly.